# Websphere server is not starting

Tags: websphere

Can someone please suggest how to forcefully start the WAS server 8.5.5.
I have mistakenly set the wrong Global security profile, and its causing me to failure of server startup.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to server profile and search for server.xml.
- Open this in editor.
- Serch the tag
- List item

Set the value enable="false".
Now you will be able to start the server. After that go to Admin console and
   update the Global security as needed. Seee below code snap for you reference..

```
<services xmi:type="pmiservice:PMIService" xmi:id="PMIService_1183122130078" enable="false" initialSpecLevel="" statisticSet="basic" synchronizedUpdate="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable security, please perform the following steps via wsadmin:

```
<WAS_INSTALL_DIR>/bin/> wsadmin -conntype NONE
wsadmin> securityoff
wsadmin> exit
```

Restart the servers.
Enable the security from administrative console.
Once the needed corrections are made, you can re-enable security in the admin console and then restart WebSphere.

NOTE: To restart the servers, you will first need to manually kill the java process since security is still enabled in the currently running process.

If this does not work, then you can try the following method.
In security.xml in the dmgr profile manually edit the file to change enable="true" to enable="false". It will be located in the first few lines of the file. Once this is done you can start up the deployment manager. If you have federated nodes you will have to manually kill them to bring them down. Then do manual syncnode to the dmgr from the command line of each node in order for them to update their local security.xml files. This will disable security on the local nodes as well.